# C# Activator.CreateInstance Error, MissingMethodException: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#

I'm programming in C# and now I have a simple question to ask.

I have three classes:

1. **internal abstract class Foo**, which has no constructor/instance defined.
2. **internal abstract class Bar : Foo**, which has a default constructor defined:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Set up defaults.
   /// </summary>
   public Bar()
   {

   }
   ```
3. **internal class Baz : Bar**. For this class, I didn't type down any default constructor. Instead, I have a constructor which accepts a few parameters, and assign values of those parameters to fields under this class.

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Set up defaults with parameters.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="parameters">GenericParams json string to use</param>
   /// <param name="startTime">Start time parameter. Must be a valid DateTime format.</param>
   /// <param name="endTime">End time parameter. Must be a valid DateTime format.</param>
   /// <param name="pageSize">Page size argument</param>
   public Baz(string parameters, string startTime, string endTime, int pageSize)
   {
       this.Parameters = parameters;
       this.StartTime = startTime;
       this.EndTime = endTime;
       this.PageSize = pageSize;
   }
   ```

However, I'm now having problem with a unit test script I have:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Unit Test 1.
    /// </summary>
    public void Test1()
    {
            ********Some Codes********
            Foo args = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Baz)) as Foo;
            Assert.IsNotNull(args);
            ********Some Codes********
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unit Test.
    /// </summary>
    public void Test2()
    {
            ********Some Codes********
            Bar args = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Baz)) as Bar;
            Assert.IsNotNull(args);
            ********Some Codes********
        }
    }
```

In my unit tests, errors are happening at the line with Activator.CreateInstance(). Is it because I didn't define the default constructor under Baz()? My guess is that, since I defined a constructor which accepts parameters for Baz(), if I want to use Activator.CreateInstance(type) to call a class's default constructor, I have to define this default constructor under Baz().

**I think my question is like, is it possible that if I defined parameterized constructor only without defining default constructor, the default constructor just doesn't exist?**

Please let me know if my guess is correct. I cannot provide more details of the unit test since this is from my company's code base. If there's anything that I didn't explain well above, please also leave a comment. I will follow up real quick.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Also, the error message is: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Comment: The msg is self explanatory. You need to define a parameterless constructor for baz

Comment: Yes, a default empty constructor is automatically added only if you do not define some constructors by yourself, so, just, yes, just create the empty constructor

Comment: Like I said, I was just making sure that my understanding is correct. I know this is a very simple question. I forgot some basic concepts over time. BUT STILL! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Steve It's still missing the method for some reason. I added the default constructor but it's still not working

Comment: @KevinYuan show your new code. my guess is that you didn't make it public

Comment: @Steve I figured it out. Somehow didn't add default constructors for other classes inherited from Bar. Thank you for your help